# How to download movies from hdmoviespoint.com in Ubuntu?

Tags: downloads, idm

On Windows I used Internet Download Manager to download movies from [hdmoviespoint.com](http://www.hdmoviespoint.com/).

Internet Download Manager automatically grabs the file from the download page (they don't provide any download link), now Internet Download Manager doesn't work in Ubuntu.

Is there any way to download movies from that site?

Comment: Is that a legal download site (hdmoviespoint.com)?

Comment: If it's legal you can use the [VideoDownloadHelper extension for firefox](http://www.downloadhelper.net/), works like a charm.

Comment: Can you expand this question with more details about exactly what Internet Download Manager did, that you need to do? Is it simply that there is a page with a download link on it, but the link is not displayed? If that's the case, you could inspect the source of the page and look for links... but I'm not sure that's what you're describing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use movgrab.

To install Movgrab:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install movgrab
```

To download a video

```
movgrab URL
```

cehck [the source](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/02/movgrab-command-line-video-downloader.html) for more information

Answer (score 2):

You can try '**XDM**' (xtreme download manager) on Ubuntu to Download files.
This package is similar to Internet download manager. And provides grabbing video links too.
To install this using command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install xdman
```

or you can install this software from software center too.

**Method 2: Installing Savefrom.net helper extension on chrome**

visit [en.savefrom.net](http://en.savefrom.net/) for more information about this extension.

Thank you.